# jq filter for object with target value or key is not exist

Tags: json, select, key, jq, jsonlines

I have  jsonlines data which and would like to find 1. value is empty object  or 2. key is not exist . In the following sample, I wonder take the result of items which .items.spec.resource={} or .items.spec.limits|requests which key not exist.

```
data='{"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"pod01"},"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"con01_01","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m"}}},{"name":"con01_02","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m"}}}]}},{"metadata":{"name":"pod02"},"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"con02_01","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m"}}},{"name":"con02_02","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m"}}}]}},{"metadata":{"name":"pod03"},"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"con03_01","resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"100m"},"requests":{"cpu":"100m"}}},{"name":"con03_02","resources":{}}]}}]}'
```

```
list=$(echo $data | jq '.items[] | select(.spec.containers[].resources.requests == null or  .spec.containers[].resources.limits == null or .spec.containers[].resources == {})')
```

```
echo $list
```

Here comes the result

```
{ 
  "metadata": { "name": "pod02" }, 
  "spec": { 
    "containers": [ 
      { "name": "con02_01", 
        "resources": { 
                       "limits": { "cpu": "100m" }, 
                       "requests": { "cpu": "100m" } 
                     } 
      }, 
      { "name": "con02_02", 
        "resources": { 
                       "limits": { "cpu": "100m" } 
                     } 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
} 
{ 
  "metadata": { "name": "pod03" },
  "spec": {
    "containers": [ 
      { 
        "name": "con03_01", 
        "resources": { 
                       "limits": { "cpu": "100m" }, 
                       "requests": { "cpu": "100m" } 
                     } 
      }, 
      { "name": "con03_02", 
        "resources": {} 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
} 

{ 
  "metadata": { "name": "pod03" }, 
  "spec": { 
    "containers": [ 
      { "name": "con03_01", 
        "resources": { 
                        "limits": { "cpu": "100m" }, 
                        "requests": { "cpu": "100m" } 
                     } 
      }, 
      { "name": "con03_02", 
        "resources": {} 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
} 
  
{ 
  "metadata": { "name": "pod03" }, 
  "spec": { 
    "containers": [ 
      { "name": "con03_01", 
        "resources": { 
                        "limits": { "cpu": "100m" }, 
                        "requests": { "cpu": "100m" } 
                      } 
      }, 
      { "name": "con03_02", 
        "resources": {} 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
}
```

I don't understand the repeat part, I guess it is because of the conditions,  how can I get the part of above conditions, I would like to filter the part of metadata and spec.containers which meet conditions.

Comment: Do you want the pod name or the container name as the output?

Comment: yes, I want the pod name and the container name as the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with your explanatory comment, it would appear you could achieve what you want using jq "$-variables":

```
jq -c '
.items[]
| .metadata.name as $podname
| .spec.containers[] 
| select(.resources.requests == null or 
         .resources.limits == null or 
         .resources == {})
| [$podname, .name]
'
```

With your data, the output produced by the above would be:

```
["pod02","con02_02"]
["pod03","con03_02"]
```

#### Simplification

The test for the third condition (.resources == {}) is actually redundant, so the above jq filter is equivalent to:

```
.items[]
| .metadata.name as $podname
| .spec.containers[] 
| select(.resources | (.requests == null or .limits == null ))
| [$podname, .name]
```

### Existence of a key

To check for the existence of a key, it is generally appropriate to use `has/1` since `{} | .key` evaluates to `null`. Thus you might wish to replace the `select()` above with:

```
select( any(.resources | has("requests", "limits"); not) )
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. It helps me a lot.